# Mongoose idGetter error: Cannot set property '_id' of null

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting the following error from the Mongoose idGetter function. Can anyone shed some light on what may be causing it?

```
  return this.$__._id = null == this._id
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '_id' of null
    at model.idGetter (e:\Users\Christine\test\mvt\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:98:23)
```

The error situation involves multiple client requests performing document removes (on different documents in the same collection), on a database being accessed over internet (i.e. slow response time). The failure happens on accessing the id of one of the removed documents. There appears to be a small timing window in which it occurs - everything I've tried to debug it causes the problem to 'go away'.

Outline of the application code:

```
Details.findOneAndRemove({ _id : remove_id}, afterRemove);

function afterRemove(err, removedDoc){
  if (!err && removedDoc){
    OtherDetails.find({ _id: some_id}, afterFind);
  }

  function afterFind(err, foundDoc){
    if (!err && foundDoc){
      // next line causes exception
      if (foundDoc.details_id === removedDoc.id) { // do stuff };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `id` property defined on the document that you have removed?

If not, you should probably want to compare `foundDoc.details_id` with `removedDoc._id`

Below is the source code for the `idGetter` function in the mongoose code base:

```
function idGetter () {
  if (this.$__._id) {
    return this.$__._id;
  }

  return this.$__._id = null == this._id
    ? null
    : String(this._id);
}
```

As I understand, I think that the `idGetter` is specifically aimed at `ObjectId` types, hence that exception.

You could also try to add an `id` property on the document if it does not yet exist to see if it continues to throw the same exception.

Comment: Details has implicit _id ObjectId.  OtherDetails.details_id is a string field, so I think the comparison is right. The code works fine most of the time, its just in the case where there are multiple parallel requests...

Comment: If the Details object only has the implicit _id, why are you using removedDoc.id? Also, regarding parallel requests, is there any chance that you might be removing the same document twice?

Comment: It is plausible that the test client is trying to remove the same document twice - I will look into that.

We're using removedDoc.id just for the convenience of getting the string representation of the ID for comparison. It should be equivalent to doing removedDoc._id.toString(), which is what we need for comparison with the foundDoc.details_id.

Comment: It's not due to removing same doc twice. Got the same error on  referencing an id in a doc that just got created (with similar parallel requests going on). It's the fact the error is occuring in the mongoose driver... and implying that the this.$__ document internal cache is null... that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw: it is possible that the problem was related to using 32-bit Node on 64-bit Windows (8.1). After installing 64-bit Node, I could not reproduce the problem.

Unsatisfying level of certainty, but I thought I would share in case anyone else gets a similar problem or can shed light on whether this might really have been the cause.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! It would also be interesting if node behaves the same on some other OS. Nevertheless, it's one of those bugs that stick with you, lingering in the back of your mind...